# facing errors in installing django-tracking

Tags: python, django

I am trying to install django-tracker and have extracted it in a directory and now when am running python setup.py i am getting the followig error

```
     vikas@vikas-laptop:~/djcode/django-tracking-0.4.1$ python setup.py
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "setup.py", line 6, in <module>
     import tracking
     File "/home/vikas/djcode/django-tracking-0.4.1/tracking/__init__.py", line 1, in      <module>
    import listeners
     File "/home/vikas/djcode/django-tracking-0.4.1/tracking/listeners.py", line 6, in       <module>
     from django.core.cache import cache
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 70, in    <module>
     if DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS not in settings.CACHES:
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in _setup
% (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
 django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings    are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Can anyone please help me out in solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give python setup.py a specific command. If you wish to install it, then do the following:

```
$ python setup.py install
```

if you wish to work on the package to enhance it, then do the following:

```
$ python setup.py develop
```

Of course, it goes without saying that this should occur within [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.org) and if you are installing the package you can do so via [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html).

Answer (score 4):

Try following alternate method:

**`pip install git+https://github.com/bashu/django-tracking.git`**

This works for me. Following is trace of the same:

```
root@3239fee56ba9:/home/docker/code/gstudio/gnowsys-ndf# pip install git+https://github.com/bashu/django-tracking.git
Collecting git+https://github.com/bashu/django-tracking.git
  Cloning https://github.com/bashu/django-tracking.git to /tmp/pip-IMNBJq-build
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django>=1.4 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from django-tracking==0.4.1)
Installing collected packages: django-tracking
  Running setup.py install for django-tracking ... done
Successfully installed django-tracking-0.4.1
```

Answer (score 1):

django-tracking needs some fixes to work with Django 1.5 and 1.6.

I've created a fork here https://github.com/pcraston/django-tracking

(fixes for Django 1.5 were copied from https://bitbucket.org/romanalexander/django-tracking)