# I can't install django-tracking in Django 1.5.4 and Ubuntu 13.04 EC2

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I'm having trouble installing the package `django-tracking` using Django 1.5.4 and Ubuntu 13.04. I've tried `pip`, `easy_install` and `python setup.py install` with no results. I get the following error message:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-164-30-68:~/django-tracking$ sudo python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tracking
  File "/home/ubuntu/django-tracking/tracking/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import listeners
  File "/home/ubuntu/django-tracking/tracking/listeners.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.core.cache import cache
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    if DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS not in settings.CACHES:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not     configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call     settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I think it may be something simple that I'm just not seeing... Django-tracking is available here: https://bitbucket.org/codekoala/django-tracking

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Refer following link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930640/facing-errors-in-installing-django-tracking/36773299#36773299

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally installed it using the [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/codekoala/django-tracking) repo instead of the Github one. I don't know what's the difference but it seems it is more up to date. By the way, the otter methods (pip and easy_install) didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

**`pip install git+https://github.com/bashu/django-tracking.git`**